# Deploying django app with channels on Daphne - SSL

Tags: python, django, ssl, nginx, daphne

I am trying to deploy a simple django app to receive websocket messages (wss).

I am using the following command:

```
daphne -e ssl:443:privateKey=key.pem:certKey=cert.cer bms_project.asgi:channel_layer
```

with the following included in the settings.py file:

```
SECURE_PROXY_SSL_HEADER = ('HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO', 'https')
SECRET_KEY = os.environ["SECRET_KEY_BMS"]
```

and the following asgi.py file:

```
import os
from channels.asgi import get_channel_layer

os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "bms_project.settings")

# secret key
os.environ["SECRET_KEY_BMS"] = "some random self-signing key off the internet"

channel_layer = get_channel_layer()
```

the following error is given:

```
 File "c:\program files\python36\lib\site-packages\django\conf\__init__.py", line 129, in __init__
raise ImproperlyConfigured("The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.")
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: The SECRET_KEY setting must not be empty.
```

I feel like I am handling the key incorrectly, no idea what the correct method is.

Answer (score 0):

If you're deploying to the server read this:http://masnun.rocks/2016/11/02/deploying-django-channels-using-daphne/

Comment: Works fine like that (without a reverse proxy), all falls apart when I try implementing ssl

Comment: @PhilS Hey. Did you find a solution for ssl?